# Why isn't my sitemap being read by Google Search Console after changing the name?

Tags: xml, sitemap

Previously my sitemap was being read by Google Search Console. I changed the name of my sitemap two weeks ago and since then it states "Sitemap could not be read." Clicking on the open sitemap link opens up my sitemap so it's the right link. Is it something with my formatting? Sitemap down below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
  <url>
    <loc>https://xman2156.github.io/TOH/</loc>
    <lastmod>2021-09-04</lastmod>
  </url>
  <url>
    <loc>https://xman2156.github.io/amphibia/</loc>
    <lastmod>2021-09-04</lastmod>
  </url>
</urlset>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `robots.txt` to the project base:

```
User-agent: *
Sitemap: https://your-domain.example/sitemap.xml
```